# Changing the View from a button within a Popover

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

I orignally had a tab bar to change views within my app. However now I've gotten rid of the tab bar and have a toolbar with a menu button. When this button is pushed, a popover comes up with buttons that will hopefully change my screen.

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `UIPopoverController` you set a `UIViewController` which can have a class where you define a protocol for the controller that creates the `UIPopoverController` notified of any action...